# How can I if my app will remember that I bought In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have made an app and made an In-App purchase for the premium version. Because I can't test In-App purchases in the Simulator.

So here is my code:

```
class settingsViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var adBennerView: ADBannerView!
@IBOutlet var outletRemoveAds: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "xxx")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func removeAds(sender: AnyObject) {
    for product in list {
        var prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "xxx") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }

}
@IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: AnyObject) {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {
    println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("product request")

    var myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        println("product added")
        println(product.productIdentifier)
        println(product.localizedTitle)
        println(product.localizedDescription)
        println(product.price)

        list.append(product as! SKProduct)
    }
    outletRemoveAds.enabled = true
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            println(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "xxx":
                println("remove ads")
                removeAds()
                isPremium = true
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    println("finish trans")
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
{
    println("remove trans");
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions restored")

    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "xxx":
            println("remove ads")
            removeAds()
            isPremium = true

        default:
            println("IAP not setup")
        }

    }
}

func removeAds() {
    adBennerView!.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

If the user bought the premium version - `isPremium` becomes `true`, so how do I know that every time the user log in `isPremium` still be true?

Comment: Test on a real device. You need to do that anyway. Never test just using the simulator.

Comment: Save a value of "1" for a NSUserdefault once transaction is successful. On app lunch check if the value is 1. If so the app is already unlocked.

Comment: @SamB But how can I test it? it doesn't work on a real device too (in test)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you only storing `isPremium` in the RAM and not anywhere else. Try using `NSUserDefaults` for that purpose, just to see how it can be done (actually it is advised not to use `NSUserDefaults` for that type of information, because it is easy to hack, but you have to understand the basics of storing information about your app state).

Comment: Is there any way I can test my in-app purchase? I think it would be better.

Comment: what do you mean by testing? test if it is bought or not?

Comment: Test if I bought or not, when I run it on my real device via xcode

Comment: It is a bad practice to check if it was bought by in-app mechanism every time. You need to manage this information by yourself in the app. Try storing in it NSUserDefaults, as I already suggested, when you will understand the basic concepts of storing information at HDD, then you will add some security such as encryption etc.

Comment: Learn what? I don't get you.

Comment: The basic of storing :)

Comment: start with NSUserDefaults. It is very easy to use. When you get your app functioning properly you would then consider adding some security.